# iOS - Porting a C program: Calling pthread_exit() in an NSOperation job

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pthreads, nsoperation

I'm trying to port a C console program over to iPhone. I have imported all the code into my project, and I'm calling it's main() in an NSOperation when the user clicks a button on the UI.

Anyway, this program is complicated and creates many of its own threads. The program calls "exit()" many times as well- this would crash the entire iPhone app, but I really want the user to be able to restart the C program if it does it.

I've been working on cleaning up these exit conditions, and I've used pthread_exit() in some of the child threads the C program creates. However, when I call pthread_exit() in the thread that is created from the NSOperation object, the app's main thread get's a SIGABRT signal and the entire app crashes.

Am I correctly assessing the situation? I am new to iOS programming so this signal may be coming from elsewhere... And if I am correct, what is the best way to get around this?

(Oh, and about using "return 0" to exit this NSOperation thread: the condition I want to exit from is nested deep in C program functions, I want to avoid changing as much structure of the program as possible, since it already very complicated)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSOperationQueue` executes it’s operations on GCD queues. While those execute their jobs on pthreads those threads are private to GCD and you are not allowed to modify or exit them using pthread APIs. There is documentation on [Compatibility with POSIX Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW18), which explicitly states which pthread functions are allowed and which not.

To solve your problem you probably should not let your pthread code run on a `NSOperationQueue` but on a new POSIX thread you create just for that.

Answer (score 1):

don't kill your pthreads -- let them exit naturally. as well, `exit` != `pthread_exit`. the author was clearly not considering cleanup when calling `exit`. so you are really just swallowing fatal errors by killing the threads.

it would be a miracle if it were incapable of resulting in undefined behaviour, or other nasty things like leaks or deadlocks.

in short, the library is being misused. you should handle the errors gracefully if you intend to continue execution. that can require a lot of work.

Comment: This is true, and while I am a little uneasy taking a cop-out in some cases, I'm trying to use these carefully. I'm not ready to get down in and reengineer the original program, but I do want to avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: The strategy I'm using so far: I'm using the debugger to see which threads are not cleaned up after executing the C program once. Then, I'm setting a flag after the original thread is complete which triggers a break in some running loops. It works, may have some memory leaks since some of these loops were never intended to end.

I'm also resetting global variables after execution. It all seems to work so far, but do you have any advice for spotting and cleaning up dangerous situations?

Comment: Oh, and I also made a wrapper for the original exit() method. If it's trying to exit with 1, I actually let it exit (except in special cases I'm choosing to recover from) but if it exits with 0, I assume that I can continue the program to run the program again... It's not perfect, but I'm working towards it.

Comment: well, if you want to try to tiptoe around the problem and attack only what you prove is present (inverse of ideal), then your exit/pthread_exit calls could just be assertion handlers -- and then do a lot of testing of your program. when you hit an assert, figure out how to exit that context or thread gracefully i really don't know the complexity of the program you are faced with, or how much of it you execute. but it also sounds like you are trying to use a single threaded program in a multithreaded context or reconstruct and reinitialize for reentrant execution, which can be a *huge* PITA =\

Comment: To be percise, I'm trying to port iPerf- but not for release on the App Store or anything. It creates a bunch of threads and things, but it does have _some_ cleanup stuff already written. An important part of iPerf is being able to cancel the program with Control-C; but getting this to working nicely on the iPhone has definately been a huge pain. I think I've safely handled normal and cancelling exit conditions, but not error conditions yet. I'm doing a lot of debugging to try and make sure I'm getting it right, but there is a lot of code.. so I'm not super sure.

Comment: Although the other answer was what I was looking for, I am taking your advice and trying to work out my uses of pthread_exit.

Comment: ok, cool. and if it really is unrecoverable... exiting may be the best solution in some of these cases. hopefully, that is not a frequent situation, of course :) good luck.